# Generate shorthand media queries via Loop, in Less

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I'm looking for a way to generate predefined media queries in Less, something like:

```
@media @small {
    color: #333;
}
```

I'd like to pull the values from a list:

```
@screens: {
    small: 320px;
    medium: 768px;
    large: 1024px;
};
```

I used to do it like this, but then I'd have to hardcode each breakpoint manually, rather than generating the screen name and size via the above list:

```
@small: ~"only screen and (min-width: 320px)";
@media: ~"only screen and (min-width: 768px)";
@large: ~"only screen and (min-width: 1024px)";
```

Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a mixin that takes two params: sreen size and rulesets.
This mixin tries to find the value of `@screen` via [each function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) and when finds, prints related media query.

```
@screens: {
    small:   320px;
    medium:  768px;
    large:  1024px;
};

.media(@screen, @rules) {
    each(@screens, {
        & when (@key = @screen) {
            @media (only screen) and (min-width: ~"@{value}") {
                @rules();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Usage. Set screen size and rulesets.

```
header {
    background-color: blue;

    .media(small, {
        background-color: red; 
    });
}
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/ePyzve).

---

Update.

If you want to use min and max values for `@media` just write necessary mixins manualy. It's much more **simple and easy to maintain**. Less lang doesn't have enough functions to work with maps and conditions.

For example:

```
@phone:   600px; // imagine phone screens are 600px and lower
@tablet:  900px; // tablets are between 601px (@phone + 1px) and 900px
@laptop: 1200px; // laptops are between 901px (@tablet + 1px) and 1200px
// large sreens are wider than 1201px (@laptop + 1px)

// @media to detect only tablets:
.tablet-only(@rules) {
  @media (only screen) and (min-width: ~"@{phone} + 1px") and (max-width: ~"@{tablet}") {
    @rules();
  }
}

// @media for tablets and wider (modile-first approach):
.tablet(@rules) {
  @media (only screen) and (min-width: ~"@{phone} + 1px") {
    @rules();
  }
}

// @media for tablets and smaller (desktop-first approach):
.tablet(@rules) {
  @media (only screen) and (max-width: ~"@{tablet}") {
    @rules();
  }
}

// Usualy you don't need to have modile-first and desktop-first @medias at the same time into one project
```

Check article at zellwk.com to learn about [mobile-first appproach](https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/).

Comment: Thanks @3rdthemagical, elegant and simple solution. Initial I thought but to not use a mixin, but why not, it's lean and does the job! I have an additional question: how would you deal with min/max values in the `@media` rule both from the list standpoint and from the mixin?

Comment: IMHO If you write this code for yourself or just for fun it's ok to try to create super-duper universal mixin that generates all possible `@medias`. But if you write this code for production and you and your colleagues have to maintain it for a long time, write as simple as possible. And you will never have a headache trying to understand what does this code do after couple of month. It is just styles =) There is no performance benefits.